# Adding New Database Drivers in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-superset, pymssql

I'm trying to install the driver pymssql according to the instruction:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/docker-add-drivers/
I didn't understand where to create the file requirements-local.txt. What is ./docker?
When i do `docker-compose build --force-rm` in the directory where it is `docker-compose.yml`it rebuilds old containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is assuming you are inside a clone of the superset github repo.

./docker refers to [this folder](https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker) present inside the superset repo

So, you are supposed to create a requirements file in the `pythonpath_dev` directory present in it